# React Native new app having issues from scratch with a lot of deprecated items

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm setting up a new project using Expo and React Native. I have just created a couple of screens: Home, Login, and Register. Currently, I don't encounter any issues, but I am receiving around 16 deprecated warnings, none of which are related to my code.

Shall i ignore them? Can i solve it? Shall i use the old cordova instead?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.